# pandas to numpy matrix conversion drops columns

Tags: pandas

I have the following data frame, but need it as a numpy array to pass into Keras. I need to preserve the month, year, shop_id and item_id columns, but the numpy array drops them and only keeps the item_category_id and avg_item_price.

```
month year shop_id item_id item_category_id  avg_item_price
01    2013 0       32                    160      147.333328
                   33                    111      347.000000
                   35                     40      247.000000
```

And at the end it says that there are

```
[32920 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Use `reset_index()` before making them matrixes.

Comment: Could you paste your code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You those columns are used as the indices in pandas, you have to reset them:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: That's done it. Thank you so much.